# Regex to match and replace string

Tags: php, regex

I want to match twitter usernames and replace it with a string. This is with PHP

This is the regex I have

```
/(^|[^a-z0-9_])[@＠]([a-z0-9_]{1,20})([@＠\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]?)/iu
```

I have a string like

```
RT @omglol I am hungry @lolomg bla
```

I want to replace every username there with a html tag like

```
<a href="http://lol.com">@omglol</a>
```

How can I do this? Thaks for answers

Comment: can you post the code you have tried too?

Comment: why is there a slim and a fat @ in this question..?

Comment: @BillyMoon Some people tweet with  @ and ＠ I want to match them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$s = "RT @omglol I am hungry @lolomg bla";
$p = "/(@\w+)/";
$r = '<a href="http://lol.com">$1</a>';
print preg_replace($p, $r, $s);

=> RT <a href="http://lol.com">@omglol</a> I am hungry <a href="http://lol.com">@lolomg</a> bla
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) for that. Since you have the regex, you just need to construct a $replacement pattern. Use `$1` and `$2` and `$3` placeholders in it, where each of them corresponds to a `(...)` capture group.

```
 $text = preg_replace(YOUR_REGEX, "$1<a href=$2>:)$2</a>$3", $text);
```

Your regex isn't very clever, but might work with that. Also you can add a base URL / prefix for the `href=` of course.

If you do need to transform the twitter name into a more complex URL somehow, then you'd probably want to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead.